# What does Presidential Revolver cost in High Noon 2?

Tags: high-noon-2

What does Presidential Revolver cost in High Noon 2? I'm curious since I'm planning on saving up some silver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Presidential Revolver is unlocked at level 25 and costs 3,000,000 silver.

Comment: This can be marked as a best answer.